# Creating a generic function bounded to integer types

Tags: generics, rust, traits

In my attempt to learn rust I am starting with some basic exercises.
I have written a simple function in what I hope is idiomatic rust to count the number of set bits in an integer.

```rust
fn bit_count(x: u32) -> u32 {
    (0..32).into_iter().map(|i| (x >> i) & 1).sum()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{} has {} set bits.", 5, bit_count(5));
}
```

Now I want to make the function generic so that I can pass any integer type: `i32`, `u32`, `i64`, `u64`... etc.

I am quite familiar with tmp in c++ but my attempt with rust generics have failed, so far I have this:

```rust
extern crate num;

fn bit_count<T>(x: T) -> T
where
    T: num::Integer + std::ops::BitAnd + std::ops::Shr + num::NumCast,
    std::ops::Range<T>: std::iter::IntoIterator,
{
    (T::zero()..num::NumCast::from(32).unwrap())
        .into_iter()
        .map(|i| (x >> num::NumCast::from(i)) & T::one())
        .sum()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{} has {} set bits.", 5, bit_count(5));
}
```

I saw the `num` crate advertised and it seemed like a good fit. I was expecting to have `T: num::Integer` and be done, however I feel like I'm spiraling down a rabbit hole here and I can't seem to get the right combination of bounds.

Any suggestions would be great! and any tips to make my code more idiomatic would also be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got there in the end. Turns out I needed to use the `num::PrimInt` trait as my bound because it includes all of the bitwise operations and casts. The `num::Integer` is less constrained and models an integer in the pure mathematical sense, so no bitwise operations.

The final code I have looks like this:

```rust
extern crate num;

fn bit_count<T>(x: T) -> T
where
    T: num::PrimInt + std::iter::Sum,
{    
    let n_bits = std::mem::size_of::<T>() * u8::BITS as usize;
    (0..n_bits).into_iter().map(|i| (x >> i) & T::one()).sum()

}

fn main() {
    println!("{} has {} set bits.", 5, bit_count(5u32));
    println!("{} has {} set bits.", 5, bit_count(5i32));
    println!("{} has {} set bits.", 5, bit_count(5i64));
}
```

It would be nice to not need that `T::one()` but it seems there's no way around it. Additionally the `std::iter::Sum` trait was needed in my bounds to allow the functional workflow.

The `num` crate actually has a function to count the number of set bits too `num::PrimInt::count_ones`.